# Ruby 1.9.3 or latest stable build (2.3.x)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm about to install ruby for an application I am developing is there a particular reason I should do the latest stable build or is 1.9.3 going to be fine for my application? (it's a simple Rails app that will call a mongoDB with some queries visualize data, download it do some analysis) What are the primary advantages to using 1.9.3 over the latest build?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 is no longer supported and no longer receives security updates. There is no downside to using the latest stable version of Ruby.

Comment: Alright thanks - I guess it's just outdate website still referring to it various guides and what not - I will proceed with the latest build then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply for safety reasons, support and updates I would decide to use the newest stable release for a new project. That's my opinion and suggestion.

Comment: I would go even further: since you know when the *next* release is going to be (always on Christmas), and you can roughly estimate how long your project is going to take, I would even suggest using the development version as soon as the first preview release is out, provided that your projected release date is significantly after Christmas.